# Update row with data from another row in the same table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update one line with another in my database. I can not find a way to do this.

I have a parent line and a child line. I want to update the PARENT activity with the CHILD activity (draft).

In my controller :

```
public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
  {
    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrateur'))
    {
        // DRAFT ACTIVITY
        $id = $request->id;
        $activity  = Activity::find($id);

        // PARENT ACTIVITY
        $parent_id = $activity->parent_id;
        $parent_activity = Activity::find($parent_id);

        DB::table('activities')->???

      }
  }
```

Can you help me ? Thank you very much !

Comment: what you want to update?

Comment: This structure doenst make sense..You find an Activity with an id, then in that Activity you have a parent_id, and then you look for Activity with parent_id..but that Activity also has a column parent_id..or am i wrong? Can you show your database structure?

Comment: Did you try `$parent_activity=$activity` and `$parent_activity->save()` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [`update`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#updates) method on your `Activity` model and pass it the new data as parameter.

Eg:

```
$parent_activity->update([
  'someProperty' => $activity->someProperty,
  ...
]);
```

Don't forget to enable [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment) by adding protected property, `$fillable`, to your `Activity` model.

To copy all data to your `$parent_activity` you could do something like:

```
$someData = $activity->toArray();

$parent_activity->update($someData);
```

Be cautioned you update only the desired properties and not lets say the `parent_id`. You can prevent this by using the `array_except()` helper.

```
$someData = array_except($activity->toArray(), ['parent_id']);

$parent_activity->update($someData);
```